# Does this diagram for pig tailing two light switches work?

Tags: electrical, lighting, electrical-panel, light-fixture

I would use 14/2 Romex coming from 15amp circuit breaker then pigtailed to 2 differnt Light switches.  [image]

Comment: You need to also show the wiring you're contemplating to run from the switches out to the lights before anyone could say for sure if you've got it right or if you're going to make a bang the 2st time you turn a switch on. Don't just show it as 3 wires entering a block box and 3 wires come out - show exactly which wires connect to which terminals on the switch.

Comment: Are these just regular switches, or smart switches?  Regular switches don't use neutral, but most smart switches do.

Comment: Just regular switches

Comment: @brhans Ill have to make a new diagram for the switches themselves.

Comment: So long as those pig-tails happen inside a box (not in the wall as it appears from your drawing), you should be fine, but again, details matter! It might be even better if you do up the actual wiring then show an actual pic of what you've done (**BEFORE turning the breaker!**) so people can see your actual work instead of just theoretical...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not quite,

Maybe confusing the naming switch with switch box.

Only hot goes to the switch and comes out as switched hot going to the lights,

The Neutral (white) does not go to the switch they are bundled together under wire nut.

The ground goes to switch box and to light box

Comment: @HABO still working on my first coffee :)

Comment: Just about all switches do have a ground connection on them as well, and although not necessary for normal operation, I would guess that somewhere in the depths of electrical code would specify that if there's a ground connection present, it should be connected to the ground system for safety.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely not. Assuming you are showing the actual switches in your diagram, when you flip a switch on, you will immediately short out the circuit!

You want the hot (black) wire connected to each switch. Then, from the other side of the switch, you will have the switched hot (black or red) going to the first fixture. The neutral (white) wire coming back from the light connects to the neutral (white) wire back to the panel.

The ground (green) wire goes to the switches and also to each light.